# I cannot execute Laragon.exe (exception EReadError in module laragon.exe at 00028A5E)

Tags: laragon

I am getting the next error message when I try to open Laragon.exe:

> exception EReadError in module laragon.exe at 00028A5E. Error reading
> Trayicon.Visible: Cannot create shell notification icon.

I have had it installed for a while, I didn't use it in this computer for few months but before it worked perfectly, what could be the problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation, the problem I don't know but the solution is just to reinstall the laragon app, restart it, and laragon will run normally again